# QML Viewtransition changes unchanged parameter?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to create a smoothly changing list in QML, but the animations have an unexpected side effect. This is my toy code that moves around items every time the window is resized:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView1
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        onWidthChanged: {
            model.move(0,1,2);
        }

        move: Transition {
               SmoothedAnimation {
                   properties: "x,y"
                   duration: 1000
               }
        }
        displaced: Transition {
                SmoothedAnimation {
                    properties: "x,y"
                    duration: 1000
                }
        }

        delegate: Item {
            x: 5
            onXChanged: {
                console.log("x: ", x)
            }

            width: parent.width
            height: 40
            Text {
                    text: name
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    font.bold: true
            }
        }
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Grey"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Red"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, this is the output when I play around with that window:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qml: x:  0.7840000000000007
qml: x:  0
qml: x:  1.2960000000000003
qml: x:  0
qml: x:  1.2960000000000003
qml: x:  0
```

And it is not just temporary, some items change their x position permanently. Is this my fault?

Comment: The delegate is like a component for a loader. So, the loader may control the position (there is no actual Loader there, but it acts like one). Maybe it's not documented, but I wouldn't rely on the x and y of the delegate. The y is completely meaningless, for example.

Comment: The problem is, the elements of the list end up with visibly different x positions.

Comment: That's not a problem. Set the leftMargin for the ListView. Or set the margin for Text: `Text { anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: 5; text: name; font.bold: true }`.